# Whats the syntax for the coproduct (disjoint union) of types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

consider the following

```
data Point=Point{x::Float,y::Float}
data Shape=Circle{centre::Point,radius::Float}
           |Rectangle {uleft::Point,bRight::Point}
```

Here the type Shape is a coproduct of two types Circle and Rectangle. I may want to reuse the types Circle and Rectangle elsewhere. So it would be useful to do this instead:

```
data Point=Point{x::Float,y::Float}
data Circle=Circle{centre::Point,radius::Float}
data Rectangle=Rectangle {uleft::Point,bRight::Point}
data Shape =Circle | Rectangle
```

but I get a compilation error when I do this: Circle is declared twice.
Whats the correct syntax for attempting this, or this not possible?

Comment: Look: http://calculist.blogspot.com.au/2008/02/true-unions.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The coproduct of types in Haskell is commonly denoted by `Either`:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

type Shape = Either Circle Rectangle
-- so you have shapes as either Left c for some Circle c
-- or Right r for some Rectangle r
```

This works quite nicely, although for technical reasons [it isn't *exactly* a coproduct](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask#Hask_is_not_Cartesian_closed). Another common way would be to define a type like so:

```
data Shape = CircleShape Circle | RectangleShape Rectangle
```

so that `CircleShape :: Circle -> Shape` and `RectangleShape :: Rectangle -> Shape` are your two injections.

It's wrong to say as you do in your question that the original `Shape` is a coproduct of types `Circle` and `Rectangle`, because the latter two aren't types. If you want to set things up so that `Circle p r` is both a value of type `Circle` and a value of type `Shape`, then that's really contrary to the spirit of Haskell's type system (although something similar might be possible with sufficiently many type system extensions).

Comment: They're value constructors, right? I like your first solution but it doesn't seem easily extendible, that is for the coproduct of three of four types.

Comment: Yes, value constructors. The second solution is more easily extensible, since you can just add constructors (might be able to come up with better names for them, as well), and is pretty much the same idea.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't directly possible, but you have a few options.  In this case, I would go with a `GADT` indexed by a `DataKind`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data ShapeType = Circle | Rectangle

data Shape :: ShapeType -> * where
     CircleShape :: { centre :: Point, radius :: Float } -> Shape Circle
     RectangleShape { uleft :: Point, bRight :: Point } -> Shape Rectangle
```

Then, whenever you wan to deal with shapes in general, you just use `Shape a`, and if you want a rectangle or a circle specifically, you use `Shape Rectangle` or `Shape Circle`, respectively.